# Rotating SVG ellipsis paths around the longer axis

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, rotation

So I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/w7rz6v45/) logo written with SVG.

I'm trying to rotate grouped ellipses around their longer axis, to create the illusion of 3D rotation.

```
    .svg-spinner3 {
    -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

Rotating them around center seems to be [easy](https://jsfiddle.net/t8ozqbdf/), but I can't seem to figure out how to rotate them (or at least skew/shrink them toward the axis untill they become a line, and then back).

Is it too hard to do? Bear in mind I'm a complete SVG newbie.

Thanks!

Comment: Scale on one axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I could just use rotate3d to do just what I intended to.

```
.svg-spinner3 {
            animation: rotation3 4s infinite linear;
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes rotation3 {
            from {
                -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
            }
            to {
                -webkit-transform: rotate3d(10, 100, 0, 360deg);
            }
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t8ozqbdf/2/
Here is a part of the solution.

Comment: Support for 3D transforms on SVG elements is very very new.  You can't rely on it working in all browsers yet.  For example, your fiddle works in Chrome, but not Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do 3D transforms on the elements inside an SVG.  So you can't, for instance, rotate around the vertical (Y) axis.

You would need to simulate the rotation by scaling the ellipse dosn in one direction only. Then back up again.

I'd also advise against using `transform-origin: 50% 50%`. Percentage values work differently between browsers. Chrome will behave the way you want, but that way is actually contrary to the specification.  Use absolute coordinates for the centre of rotation. For your shape, the equivalent of (50%, 50%) seems to be approx (230.7, 198.4).

So what we need to do to scale on the rotated axis of the ellipses, is to:
  1. rotate the ellipse to the vertical
  2. scale up or down as needed
  3. rotate the ellipse back to its original rotation

For the example ellipse I chose below, the angle we needed to use was 28 degrees.  So our transform is:

```
transform: rotate(28deg) scale(0.01, 1) rotate(-28deg);
```

Be aware that scaling by 0 is not allowed. So you need to use a very small value for the scale, instead of zero.

*Notes*

Your shapes all have an existing identical transform on them (`translate(-152.27, -120.27)`). To make things less complicated, I've put all the ellipses in a parent group and moved the common transform to that group.

Finally, note that there is one other complication.  When you scale like this, you are not only scaling the width of the ellipse, you are also scaling the width of the ellipse lines.  That may destroy the illusion of proper 3D rotation, when you start animating it.

```css
.rotate-and-scale {
  transform-origin: 230.7px 198.4px;
  transform: rotate(28deg) scale(0.01, 1) rotate(-28deg);
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-100 -100 500.47 500.47">
        <defs>
            <style>
                .cls-12,
                .cls-8 {
                    fill-rule: evenodd;
                }

                .cls-8 {
                    fill: url(#radial-gradient-8);
                }

                .cls-12 {
                    fill: url(#radial-gradient-12);
                }

            </style>
            <radialGradient id="radial-gradient" cx="232.26" cy="170.66" r="36.06" gradientTransform="translate(-138.19 -72.22) scale(1.59)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0.35" stop-color="#00aeef" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#00609c" />
            </radialGradient>
            <radialGradient id="radial-gradient-8" cx="232.4" cy="170.47" r="38.82" xlink:href="#radial-gradient" />
            <radialGradient id="radial-gradient-12" cx="231.93" cy="170.21" r="48.97" xlink:href="#radial-gradient" />
        </defs>
        <title>fadsf</title>

        <g transform="translate(-152.27 -120.27)">
        <path class="svg-spinner0 cls-12" d="M175,143a77.74,77.74,0,1,0,55-22.77A77.26,77.26,0,0,0,175,143Zm.67,109.26A76.8,76.8,0,1,1,230,274.78,76.34,76.34,0,0,1,175.7,252.29Z" />

        <path class="svg-spinner2 cls-8" d="M248.31,129c-8.67,2.55-18.08,8.5-27.18,17.22a137.76,137.76,0,0,0-25,33.25c-9.92,18.15-15.7,37.18-16.23,53.57s4.28,28.4,13.57,33.48c5.52,3,12.14,3.42,19.69,1.22,8.68-2.55,18.08-8.49,27.18-17.21a137.87,137.87,0,0,0,25-33.26,138.19,138.19,0,0,0,14.52-39,90.29,90.29,0,0,0,1.76-17,53.88,53.88,0,0,0-2-15.13c-2.21-7.54-6.13-12.9-11.65-15.91S255.85,126.84,248.31,129ZM194,265.73c-18.61-10.18-17.25-48.65,3-85.77a136.86,136.86,0,0,1,24.8-33c9-8.61,18.25-14.48,26.78-17,7.29-2.14,13.68-1.76,19,1.14s9.06,8.06,11.2,15.33c2.51,8.55,2.57,19.51.18,31.72a137.57,137.57,0,0,1-14.41,38.72h0a137.48,137.48,0,0,1-24.8,33c-9,8.6-18.26,14.48-26.79,17C205.63,269,199.25,268.63,194,265.73Zm71.38-48.41Z" />

        <path class="rotate-and-scale" fill="red" d="M248.31,129c-8.67,2.55-18.08,8.5-27.18,17.22a137.76,137.76,0,0,0-25,33.25c-9.92,18.15-15.7,37.18-16.23,53.57s4.28,28.4,13.57,33.48c5.52,3,12.14,3.42,19.69,1.22,8.68-2.55,18.08-8.49,27.18-17.21a137.87,137.87,0,0,0,25-33.26,138.19,138.19,0,0,0,14.52-39,90.29,90.29,0,0,0,1.76-17,53.88,53.88,0,0,0-2-15.13c-2.21-7.54-6.13-12.9-11.65-15.91S255.85,126.84,248.31,129ZM194,265.73c-18.61-10.18-17.25-48.65,3-85.77a136.86,136.86,0,0,1,24.8-33c9-8.61,18.25-14.48,26.78-17,7.29-2.14,13.68-1.76,19,1.14s9.06,8.06,11.2,15.33c2.51,8.55,2.57,19.51.18,31.72a137.57,137.57,0,0,1-14.41,38.72h0a137.48,137.48,0,0,1-24.8,33c-9,8.6-18.26,14.48-26.79,17C205.63,269,199.25,268.63,194,265.73Zm71.38-48.41Z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Check my solution above!